# using weakref to get exit child windows in PyQt4

Tags: python, pyqt4, weak-references

I am trying to take advantage of weakref.ref that if the main window object is deleted then the child window should close with it.

Here is the example I have tried, but is not working as expected :

```
import sys
import weakref
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

print __file__

class ParentWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    """docstring for ParentWindow"""
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(ParentWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setWindowTitle("Parent Window")
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 250, 150)
        self._setupUi()
        self._connections()
        self.childObj = ChildWindow()
        self.uiDict = weakref.ref(self, self._closeChild)

    def _closeChild(self):
        self.childObj.close()

    def _setupUi(self):
        self.btn = QtGui.QPushButton("Launch child window in child thread")
        self.setCentralWidget(self.btn)


    def _connections(self):
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.callChild)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def callChild(self):
        self.childObj.show()

class ChildWindow(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(ChildWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setWindowTitle("Child Window")
        self.byeBtn = QtGui.QPushButton("Bye", self)
        self.childLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.childLayout.addWidget(self.byeBtn)
        self.setLayout(self.childLayout)
        self.byeBtn.clicked.connect(self.close)

    def __del__(self):
        print "Exiting"

def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setApplicationName('Parent')
    pWinObj = ParentWindow()
    pWinObj.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

right now when I am closing the main window its not happening.

Comment: Given that `pWinObj = ParentWindow()`, there's still that reference so the weakref won't trigger. Why not just overload the `close` method of the `ParentWindow`?

Comment: I am thinking of a case when parent will have many child windows open...